# Modify the standard Sharepoint Rich Text Editor?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to modify the standard sharepoint Rich Text Editor control so that I can add a button to upload images easily by browsing the site's picture libraries and adding a reference to the image in the body of the editor.

please tell me what I need to do to achieve this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got what I wanted from these links:

http://www.notesfor.net/post/2009/01/21/Enhance-SharePoint-rich-text-field.aspx
http://spnote.com/be/post/2009/06/16/ImprovedRichTextField.aspx

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Telerik's RadEditor for SharePoint 2007 offers that functionality. It can be deployed as a replacement for de OOB rich text editor.

Comment: thanks but I want to know if this can be achieved using OOB tools

Comment: It can't without getting neck deep in development - that is unlikely to be cheaper than buying 3rd party.